# apply different function on each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns `field` and `value`(number of rows maximum 10). I need to perform some checks depending on the field(ie need to apply different function on each row) and store its result in `status` column. Below is sample:

```
data = {
    'field': ['a', 'b'],
    'value': [5, 20],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print('Initial DF')
print(f"{df=}")

def _check_field_a(value):
    _min = 1
    _max = 10

    if _min <= value <= _max:
        return True
    return False

def _check_field_b(value):
    
    values = [10, 20, 30, 40]

    if value in values:
        return True
    return False

func = [_check_field_a, _check_field_b]

df['status'] = df.apply(lambda row: func[row.name](row['value']), axis=1)

print('After check DF')
print(f'{df=}')
```

**output**

```
Initial DF
df=  field  value
0     a      5
1     b     20

After check DF
df=  field  value  status
0     a      5    True
1     b     20    True
```

The above code is working, just wondering is there any other better way to achieve the same?

**Edit-1**
Getting inspired from all below answers, I have modified the code but currently not working.

```
data = {
    'field': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'value': [5, 20, 80],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('Initial DF')
print(f"{df=}")

conditions = {
    'a': {'values': (1, 10), 'check_type': 'between'},
    'b': {'values': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'check_type': 'isin'},
    'c': {'values': (50, 100), 'check_type': 'between'},
}

df['status'] = False

for key, condition in conditions.items():
    if condition['check_type'] == 'between':
        df['status'] = df.loc[df['field'] == key].between(condition['values'])
    elif condition['check_type'] == 'isin': 
        df['status'] = df.loc[df['field'] == key].isin(condition['values'])

print('After check DF')
print(f'{df=}')
```

**Edit-2**
Using `np.select`, This is working and so can add as many fields easily

```
data = {
    'field': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'value': [5, 20, 80],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('Initial DF')
print(f"{df=}")

condlist = [df['field'] == 'a', df['field'] == 'b', df['field'] == 'c']
choicelist = [df['value'].between(1,10), df['value'].isin([10,20,30,40]), df['value'].between(50,100)]

df['status'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, False)

print('After check DF')
print(f'{df=}')
```

Comment: Are your rows all named 0 or 1? You say that you can have up to 10 rows. It seems from the way the functions are named and the values in the field column that you should use that column to select which function to apply. Is that just a coincidence?

Comment: Hi Joe, I am using dataframe index because I have created the function list and accessing via index. As I was not able to access through field name, otherwise there is no use of index as such.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  Can your data have up to 10 rows?  How would you use your code on `data = {'field': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'value': [5, 20, 13]}`?  By manually making the list `func` have three elements in the correct order?

Comment: Hi joe, please check updated code in edit-1 section.

Comment: What do you mean "inspired" by the answers? Is one of them correct? If so, accept it.

Comment: I am trying to implement @Quang solution for multiple rows ie `field`=[a,b,c,d... j] and they can have `between` or `isin` type.

Comment: @winter look at `np.select` instead of `np.where` if you have more than 2 fields.

Comment: Oh, btw, with *maximum number of row be 10*, I don't think there much improvement in any of the solutions.

Comment: Hi Quang, Thanks. I tried using `np.select` it is working. Please check `edit-2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your two specific functions, you can vectorize them:

```
df['output'] = np.where(
    df['field'] == 'a',
    df['value'].between(1,10), # change min,max here if needed
    df['value'].isin([10,20,30,40])
)
```

Comment: Always better to vectorize when possible!

Answer (score 0):

```
you can also use a dictionary 

import pandas as pd

data = {
    'field': ['a', 'b'],
    'value': [5, 20],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print('Initial DF')
print(df)

def check_field_a(value):
    return 1 <= value <= 10

def check_field_b(value):
    return value in [10, 20, 30, 40]

# Map fields to their respective functions
check_functions = {'a': check_field_a, 'b': check_field_b}


df['status'] = df.apply(lambda row: check_functions[row['field']](row['value']), axis=1)

print('\nAfter check DF')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with multiple conditions.

```
a_min = 1
a_max = 10
b_vals = [10,20,30,40]

df['status'] = np.where(
                        ((df['field']=='a') & (df['value'].between(a_min, a_max))) |
                        ((df['field']=='b') & (df['value'].isin(b_vals))),
                        True,
                        False
                       )
```

Comment: what's the point of `np.where` when the options are just `True/False`?

Comment: Hello @QuangHoang. If I'm not mistaken, you also used `np.where` in your answer. I'm just using it in a different way. Ultimately both answers use `np.where` to accomplish the task requested by OP.

Comment: I mean `np.where(condition, True, False)` is identical to `condition`, `np.where` only adds unnecessary processing in this case. My `np.where` usage is totally different.